# How to search with range attributes rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use bootstrap-slider and now I do filter by diameter to show only selected range to users and have problems with diameter params

my form

```
<%= form_tag @sub_category, method: 'get' do |d| %>
<%= text_field_tag "diameter[]", nil, id: "ex2", :data => {'slider-min' => '1','slider-max' => '1000','slider-step' => '5','slider-value' => '[250,450]' } %>
<%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

controller action

```
def show
        @sub_category = SubCategory.friendly.find(params[:id])
        @items = @sub_category.items
        @items = @sub_category.items.where("size >= ?", params[:diameter].first) if params[:diameter].present?
        @items = @sub_category.items.where("size <= ?", params[:diameter].last) if params[:diameter].present?
        @items = @items
    end
```

and diameter params from form

```
Processing by SubCategoriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "diameter"=>["21,451"], "commit"=>"Save"
```

How divide diameter params to 21 and 451?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `diameter` returns a coma delimited string inside an array. You should parse it:

```
def show
  @sub_category = SubCategory.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @items = @sub_category.items
  if params[:diameter].present?   
    min, max = params[:diameter].first.split(',')
    @items = @items.where("size >= ? and size <= ?", min, max)
  end
end
```

Comment: `where(size: (min..max))` would be recommendable